# Is sorting better in this situation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Assume that there is a set of points in Cartesian Coordinates and wants to find four extreme points such as x-min, y-min, x-max, and y-max.

If one uses sorting the points by x- and y- coordinates separately, it will take O(n log n) * 2.

To find the four extreme points without sorting, it will take O(n) * 4. (it has to compare the points from the beginning to the end)

Once we sort the points, finding the next four extreme points can be taken O(1), isn't it?

But without sorting, it will take O(n) * 4  again. or O(n-4) * 4 ? next time O(n-8)*4 , O(n-12) * 4 and so on???

So if we want to find the four extreme points recursively until there is no point to find. With sorting takes O(n log n), but without sorting how much time it will take? Is it O(n)?

Finding the four extreme points recursively with sorting can be better in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once we sort the points, finding the next four extreme points can be taken O(1), isn't it?

Yes.

> But without sorting, it will take O(n) * 4 again. or O(n-4) * 4 ? next time O(n-8)*4 , O(n-12) * 4 and so on???

Yes.

> So if we want to find the four extreme points recursively until there is no point to find. With sorting takes O(n log n), but without sorting how much time it will take? Is it O(n)?

By "recursively" you probably mean "iteratively". But otherwise, without sorting it will take O(n^2). Don't forget that you need to find *n* sequential extremes, which multiplies the complexity of this approach by n.

> Finding the four extreme points recursively with sorting can be better in this situation?

Indeed it is, because of the lower complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Constant factors don't matter in Big O complexity notation. `O(100000n)` is the same as `O(n +/- 100000)` which is the same as `O(n)`.

Finding the extreme points recursively until there is no point to find will take you `O(n^2)` time, since for the `i`th (1 based) extreme point you'll have to perform `n - i + 1` comparisons, i.e. `n` comparisions for the first, `n - 1` for the second and so on which gives a total of `n(n + 1)/2` comparisons, which is the same as `O(n^2)` as `n^2` is the bigger factor.

Sorting the points, on the other hand, will take `O(n log n)` time (assuming quick sort or merge sort). Finding the `n` extreme points in order will take you `O(n)` (having to iterate through the sorted array(s) once) *if* you have to use a different representation. In either case, the time complexity will remain `O(n log n)` since it is the bigger factor.

So yes, sorting is the more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

For a given axis, you should be able to find max and min in one iteration (o(n)).

```
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i : xAxisArray){
        if(i < min){
            min = i;
        }
        if(i > max){
            max = i;
        }
    }
```

So that way it would be o(n)*2. So, you can use this instead of sorting but this is only if you have to do it once.

If you need to do this for all points, sorting is the way to go.

Comment: The asker wants to find *all* extreme points, i.e. the second extreme point after the first, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting reduces to your problem: given a set of reals, [x1, ..., xn], construct the 2d set of points (x1, x1), (x2, x2), ..., (xn, xn). Once you've iteratively found all extremal points until there's no points left, you can easily reconstruct a sorted version of x1, ..., xn. That means that no algorithm that solves your problem can work faster than sorting.

Since you can also solve your problem by sorting, you have proven that the complexity of sorting is both an upper and lower bound for your problem.